# How to set one column as a color (hue) with label on top

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, seaborn

[My Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDV1o.png)
This is my dataframe

```
                 release_year    genre   count
     0              1960         Drama    13
     1              1961         Drama    16
     2              1962         Drama    21
     3              1963         Drama    13
     .
     .
     .
     6              1966         Comedy   16
```

Here is my code

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 6))
    title = fig.suptitle("Which genres are most popular from year to year?", fontsize=14, 
    fontweight='bold')


    fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, wspace=0.3)

    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.set_xlabel("Year")
    ax.set_ylabel("Production Count") 
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8.5)

    bar = ax.bar(popular['release_year'],   # i.e. [6, 5, 7, 4, 8, 3, 9]
         popular['count'], # i.e. [2836, 2138, 1079, 216, 193, 30, 5]
         edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)
```

[My Bar Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSfnN.png) 
This is what I got

How do I get the column 'genre' included in the plot? There are two different types (Drama and Comedy) and I want each bar to have categorized color accordingly to what they fall under. I would like to make into a label as well on top so it can be visualized well.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Added just right now!

Answer (score 0):

Directly with matplotlib, you could color the bars as follows. Creating a legend requires some [custom code](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

years = range(1960, 1991)
popular = pd.DataFrame({'release_year': years,
                        'genre': np.random.choice(['Drama', 'Comedy'], len(years)),
                        'count': np.random.randint(20, 50, len(years))})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 6))
title = fig.suptitle("Which genres are most popular from year to year?", fontsize=14,
                     fontweight='bold')

fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, wspace=0.3)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
genre_color = {'Drama': 'crimson', 'Comedy': 'limegreen'}
ax.bar(popular['release_year'],
       popular['count'],
       color=[genre_color[i] for i in popular['genre']],
       edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)
ax.set_xlabel("Year")
ax.set_ylabel("Production Count")
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8.5)
legend_elements = [Patch(facecolor=genre_color[gen], edgecolor='b', label=gen)
                   for gen in genre_color]
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting bar plot]

PS: [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) also has some standard functionality to generate bar plots (`dodge=False` prevents that the code expects separate genre columns per year). Note that in general changing ticks and labels best happens after creating the bar plot, not before. E.g. Seaborn sets its own labels, and you can change them afterwards.

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x='release_year', y='count', data=popular, hue='genre', palette=genre_color, dodge=False)
```